# Different forms per user role

Tags: 7, display-suite

I need to hide the *description* field from regular users when entering data, but the field should be visible to administrator users, which also can edit it. I used the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module to hide that field by using different view modes, but I could not figure it out how to hide the field on forms. Any guidance would be appreciated!

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: I don't think that's possible using Display Suite. It looks like the [User role field](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_role_field) module does what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display Suite is not what you need, [`field_permissions`](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) is, check out the screen.

DS is mostly used to change the global look and the availability of some fields and labels (like Teaser, Product, Fullpage ...)

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben - Thanks a lot for sharing this module with me. One issue I see here is that I use `col-md-6` and have 2 columns but I want to be able to change the layout too for different user views. Would this module help with that too or would you recommend another module for it.

Comment: This seems to be very specific, too specific to be handled by a single module. In my opinion, you can try with Drupal Form States API (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7.x)

Comment: much appreciated thank you!